# Replace / Remove Shortcode after 1st run / post

Tags: shortcode, customization

I want to use a shortcode to replace it with an image form a url.

My idea:

```
[shortcode url="http://google.de/aImage.jpg"]
```

I post this shortcode usinbg IFTTT. After publishing the article the shortcode should be replaced by the image. But the image should come from my "local" library. So the shortcode should download the image, replace it self with a html tag for the image in the library ... that's it :-D

Is it possible to use a shortcode that way? How?

Comment: Hi Patrick, could you provide more details on what you've tried already (and why it didn't work)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample post should be the content.

> Samplepost
>   {IFTTTImageFetch="https://drscdn.500px.org/photo/132307433/m%3D900/4c2b5e1f7f8c4d4a11a56f8f3cfdc565"}
>   some stuff ..asd asd asd

```
  function getImageUrlOutOfContent($content)
    {
        preg_match_all('/\\{IFTTTImageFetch="([^"]+)"\\}/i', $content, $matches);
        $url = $matches[1][0];
        importRemoteMedia($url, $post->ID);     
        $content = str_replace($url, "", $content);
        return $content;
    }
    add_filter('content_save_pre', 'getImageUrlOutOfContent', 10, 1);
```

It should parse the prefix and the url - do the download stuff ... and remove it form the content ... but it does't even show a match...

Comment: fixed it with a workaround ... explode - and splitted the string by my own.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a shortcode in a traditional sense. You could use something like `{imageurl=""http://google.de/aImage.jpg}`

You would use the filter [`content_save_pre`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/content_save_pre) to run before the content is saved to the database a search and replace with the img markup which you get from [`media_sideload_image()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_sideload_image/). `media_sideload_image()` downloads the image from a URL adds it to the media manager and then return the img markup.

Have a look how [`wp_make_content_images_responsive()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_make_content_images_responsive/) works. It something similar as it replaces the old img forma with the responsive image format.

Comment: Thank you- good idea.
But I have some trouble with the add_filter('content_save_pre', 'getImageUrlOutOfContent', 10, 1); - I think.

function getImageUrlOutOfContent($content)
{
 preg_match_all('/\\{IFTTTImageFetch="([^"]+)"\\}/i', $content, $matches);
 $url = $matches[1][0];
 $content = str_replace($url, "", $content);
 return $content;
}

The content will not be replaced or it will be 0.

Comment: I would first debug the matches result. So edd `error_log(print_r(,true));` but don't forget to activate `define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);`. Then you can check the results in `wp-content/debug.log`